# How to reset the number inside "In [ ]" from Jupyter Notebook cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am a newbie to Jupyter and trying to learn it. I ran a cell four times and now there's In[4] and Out[4] and if I execute again, it increases. Now how can I reset the values?

Also why are these values stored? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's so that if you have a lot of cells you can have a record of what order you ran them in. To reset the counter, you reset the kernel, either via the Kernel menu or by pressing "0" twice.